# Python: MemoryError, my code is not memory efficient

Tags: python, arrays, out-of-memory

I got a coding quiz:
[a,b,c,d,e,f] where a != b != c != d != e != f

Find every possible number from 1-6 for a,b,c,d,e,f where (b+c)-a = (d+e+f)-(b+c).

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy
perm = permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
for i in list(perm):
    my_array = numpy.asarray(i)
    if (my_array[1] + my_array[2]) - my_array[0] == (my_array[3] + my_array[4] + my_array[5]) - (my_array[1] + my_array[2]):
        print(my_array)
    else:
        pass
```

The code works fine but it is not memory efficient.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: `list(perm)` remove the list call

Comment: Why are you doing `list(perm)` instead of just iterating over `perm`?

Comment: Also, why are you using `numpy.asarray(i)`??? That isn't cuaing the memory error, but it makes no sense. Why use numpy *at all*?

Comment: Note that "a != b != c != d != e" does not imply "the five numbers are two-by-two distinct". For instance, 3 != 4 != 3.

Answer (score 0):

**First, it's good practice to avoid loops whenever you can**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization

**Also, good to look at the underlying math to see if it can lead to further optimization**: I'm not a mathematician so there might be room for more, but already we can say that:

```
b+c-a=d+e+f-(b+c)
(b+c)-a - ((d+e+f)-(b+c))=0    # moving everything to the left
-a+2b+2c-d-e-f=0  # consolidating terms
```

So now that it's a simple sum of terms, **we can process with Numpy more efficiently**:

```
from itertools import permutations
import time
import numpy as np

low = 1
high = 6
perms = np.array(list(permutations(range(low, high + 1))))
print('permutations cnt:', perms.shape[0])

time_np = 0
time_loop = 0
runs = 1000
for run in range(0, runs):
    # ---------------------------------------------
    # NUMPY
    # ---------------------------------------------
    start = time.process_time()
    equation = np.zeros((perms.shape[0], 6))
    equation[:, 0] = -perms[:, 0]  # -a
    equation[:, 1] = 2 * perms[:, 1]  # +2b
    equation[:, 2] = 2 * perms[:, 2]  # +2c
    equation[:, 3] = -perms[:, 3]  # -d
    equation[:, 4] = -perms[:, 4]  # -e
    equation[:, 5] = -perms[:, 5]  # -f
    sum = np.sum(equation, axis=1)  # summing up rows
    matches_np = sum == 0  # = 0
    end = time.process_time()
    time_np += end - start

    # ---------------------------------------------
    # LOOP
    # ---------------------------------------------
    start = time.process_time()
    matches_loop = []
    for i in perms:
        (a, b, c, d, e, f) = i
        if b + c - a == (d + e + f - (b + c)):
            matches_loop.append(i)
    end = time.process_time()
    time_loop += end - start


# ---------------------------------------------
# COMPARING
# ---------------------------------------------
time_np_avg = time_np / runs
time_loop_avg = time_loop / runs
print('\nNumpy method:')
print('  matches cnt:', matches_np.sum())
print('  avg time spent (sec):', '%f' % time_np_avg)
print('\nLoop method:')
print('  matches cnt:', len(matches_loop))
print('  avg time spent (sec):', '%f' % time_loop_avg)
print('\nNumpy is', time_loop_avg / time_np_avg, ' faster than loop')
```

And the result:

[image]

**So even if for low computation tasks like this one it still performs OK with a loop**, I strongly recommend you look at the math side AND start writing your code with libraries like Numpy (and later acceleration with CUDA etc...) to build the habit of writing efficient code.

Comment: I think that's handling what I call "case 2", where every element `a, b, c, ...` is assumed distinct. The problem statement says otherwise.

Comment: True I didn't pay attention to that, well I guess with your and my answer the SO should have what he/she needs in terms of completeness/speed

Comment: LOL, and all that for a quiz!... I was looking for guidelines about quiz questions (it somewhat bothers me personally that people do that instead of honestly trying themselves --which should be fun anyway, otherwise they may want to save time and look for other career paths). [This post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152379/909215) seems appropriate and reasonable to me.

Comment: Indeed. I had a few minutes to kill waiting for my gf to go somewhere, so just wrote the little piece without giving it too much thought :) I see no issue answering a question (the question itself isn't evil), I think the responsibility sits with the person asking it. In the end, if your mindset is to always rely on others to do the work for you, you'll never improve, which defeats the attempt at learning. You may pass an exam. get a certificate, but sooner or later you'll get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, `a != b != c ...` is not equivalent to `len({a,b,c,...}) == len([a,b,c,...])`. The former (which I'll call case 1) is [defined](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) as pairwise comparisons, while the latter (case 2) tests if each element is distinct (present only once).

For case 1, we need to create a new generator inspired from the cartesian [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but modified to never yield results where adjacent values are the same:

```py
def product_pairwise_distinct(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool if not x or x[-1] != y]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Example:

```py
>>> list(product_pairwise_distinct(range(3), repeat=3))
[(0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 2),
 (0, 2, 0),
 (0, 2, 1),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 2),
 (1, 2, 0),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (2, 0, 1),
 (2, 0, 2),
 (2, 1, 0),
 (2, 1, 2)]
```

With this in hand, you can easily write your functions (either case1 or case 2):

```py
def gen_matches_repeat():
    # case 1
    for a, b, c, d, e, f in product_pairwise_distinct(range(1, 7), repeat=6):
        if b + c - a == d + e + f - (b + c):
            yield a, b, c, d, e, f
```

and

```py
def gen_matches_distinct():
    # case 2
    for a, b, c, d, e, f in permutations(range(1, 7)):
        if b + c - a == d + e + f - (b + c):
            yield a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Case 1:

```py
>>> len(list(gen_matches_repeat()))
1278

>>> list(gen_matches_repeat())[:10]
[(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1)]
```

Case 2:

```py
>>> len(list(gen_matches_distinct()))
144

>>> list(gen_matches_distinct())[:10]
[(1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6),
 (1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4),
 (1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6),
 (1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3),
 (1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3),
 (1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6),
 (1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 5),
 (1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6),
 (1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2)]
```

Comment: just one que , why can't I run this : "[tuple(pool) for pool in range(3)] * 3" ,
directly.